# Devise authentication error with ActionController::Responder and axlsx_rails gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise, axlsx

Added an export-to-xlsx option with the [axlsx](https://github.com/randym/axlsx) and [axlsx_rails](https://github.com/straydogstudio/axlsx_rails) gems to an [existing Rails 4.2.0 app](https://github.com/cfmeyers/DocketDonkey/tree/fix-excel) that uses Devise for authentication.  Export to xlsx now works properly:

[app/controllers/cases_controller.rb](https://github.com/cfmeyers/DocketDonkey/blob/fix-excel/app/controllers/cases_controller.rb):

```
class CasesController < ApplicationController
  def create
  ⋮
    @public_fields = public_fields

    respond_to do |format|
      ⋮
      format.xlsx { render :xlsx => "create", :filename => "cases.xlsx" }
    end

  end

end
```

[app/views/cases/create.xlsx.axlsx](https://github.com/cfmeyers/DocketDonkey/blob/fix-excel/app/views/cases/create.xlsx.axlsx):

```
wb = xlsx_package.workbook

wb.add_worksheet(name: 'Cases') do |sheet|
    sheet.add_row @public_fields

    @cases.each do |kase|
      sheet.add_row( @public_fields.map { |field| kase[field] } )
    end
end
```

However, the previously working authentication stopped working.  Accessing the Devise `sign_in` or `sign_up` routes, either by clicking the links or by navigating to prompts this error:

```
NoMethodError in Users::SessionsController#new
undefined method `call' for ActionController::Responder:Class
```

Extracted source (around line #203):

```
(options.delete(:responder) || self.class.responder).call(self, resources, options)
```

Trace

```
responders (2.1.0) lib/action_controller/respond_with.rb:203:in `respond_with'
devise (3.4.1) app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb:11:in `new'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:198:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:234:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:234:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:234:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:234:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:234:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:151:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:151:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:151:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:151:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:151:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:151:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:151:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:151:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `_run_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:734:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:236:in `block in action'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:42:in `serve'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:49:in `serve'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:802:in `call'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:647:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/migration.rb:378:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `_run_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:734:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
web-console (2.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/debug_exceptions.rb:18:in `middleware_call'
web-console (2.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/debug_exceptions.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:113:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/application.rb:164:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:81:in `block in pre_process'
thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:79:in `catch'
thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:79:in `pre_process'
thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:54:in `process'
thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:39:in `receive_data'
eventmachine (1.0.5) lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run_machine'
eventmachine (1.0.5) lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run'
thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/backends/base.rb:63:in `start'
thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/server.rb:159:in `start'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:19:in `run'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/server.rb:286:in `start'
railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/commands/server.rb:80:in `start'
railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `'
bin/rails:8:in `require'
bin/rails:8:in `'
spring (1.3.3) lib/spring/client/rails.rb:27:in `load'
spring (1.3.3) lib/spring/client/rails.rb:27:in `call'
spring (1.3.3) lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
spring (1.3.3) lib/spring/client.rb:26:in `run'
spring (1.3.3) bin/spring:48:in `'
spring (1.3.3) lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
spring (1.3.3) lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `'
/Users/collin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/Users/collin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
bin/spring:13:in `'
bin/rails:3:in `load'
bin/rails:3:in `'
```

I know that [axlsx_rails patches](https://github.com/straydogstudio/axlsx_rails/blob/5355aa38e379bc5102e2aa1ccafb7f9d706d6e8c/lib/axlsx_rails/action_controller.rb) `ActionController::Responder`.  Has this change broken Devise?

Comment: Which version of axlsx_rails are you using?

Comment: If it is 0.3.0, please create an issue on https://github.com/straydogstudio/axlsx_rails and include the contents of your Gemfile. A small github repo would be even better if you have time.

Comment: Noel, thanks for checking this out!  I'm using devise 3.4.1, axlsx 1.3.6, axlsx_rails 0.1.5.  You think I should use the latest (0.3.0)from github?

Comment: You'll want to use 0.3.0. It was specifically for Rails 4.2. I'm not sure what magic Devise has within it, so we will have to see the results.

Comment: Do let me know the results by the way, good or bad. Thanks!

Comment: noel, updated to 0.3.0, it works!  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Noel (from the comments) was correct:  I was using the wrong version of axlsx_rails with rails 4.2.  I fixed this and it works perfectly.

Comment: Which version you were using?

Comment: I think it is 0.3.0

Comment: Bravo! This was exactly the issue I encountered after including an old gem in my gemfile that was unexpectedly dependent on an older version of axlsx_rails!

Comment: My two cents here: update worked for Rails 5.2.1, axlsx_rails version as 0.5.2.