# Rails: Why server is getting a fatal error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

my rails app is getting a fatal error related with devise i think. the error message is not clear for me and i didn't make any changes to that may create this error.

**EDIT: log file link :**https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HdNnMsHTR0mULqMNKbyM5ZHW7nTXjhoH/view?usp=drivesdk

To solve the issue, I have retarted unicorn service and even server restart both of which didn t solve.

Below you cam see the log message. I will appreciate if you can guode me how to solve this issue.

```
F,[2019-05-18T14:26:17.175396 #1883] FATAL -- : [2adb42f5-0603-4e2a-b1bc-835fbb6223a5]   F, [2019-05-18T14:26:17.175536 #1883] FATAL -- : [2adb42f5-0603-4e2a-b1bc-835fbb6223a5] NoMethodError (undefined method `call' for ActionController::Responder:Class                Did you mean?  caller):
F, [2019-05-18T14:26:17.175559 #1883] FATAL -- : [2adb42f5-0603-4e2a-b1bc-835fbb6223a5]   F, [2019-05-18T14:26:17.175585 #1883] FATAL -- : [2adb42f5-0603-4e2a-b1bc-835fbb6223a5] responders (2.4.0) lib/action_controller/respond_with.rb:211:in `respond_with'              [2adb42f5-0603-4e2a-b1bc-835fbb6223a5] devise (4.5.0) app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb:14:in `new'                                                                     [2adb42f5-0603-4e2a-b1bc-835fbb6223a5] actionpack (5.0.7) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'                                                   [2adb42f5-0603-4e2a-b1bc-835fbb6223a5] actionpack (5.0.7) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:188:in `process_action'                                                                   [2adb42f5-0603-4e2a-b1bc-835fbb6223a5] actionpack (5.0.7) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:30:in `process_action'                                                           [2adb42f5-0603-4e2a-b1bc-835fbb6223a5] actionpack (5.0.7) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'                                                      [2adb42f5-0603-4e2a-b1bc-835fbb6223a5] activesupport (5.0.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:126:in `call'                                                                          [2adb42f5-0603-4e2a-b1bc-835fbb6223a5] activesupport (5.0.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:506:in `block (2 levels) in compile'                                                   [2adb42f5-0603-4e2a-b1bc-835fbb6223a5] activesupport (5.0.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:455:in `call'                                                                          [2adb42f5-0603-4e2a-b1bc-835fbb6223a5] activesupport (5.0.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:101:in `__run_callbacks__'                                                             [2adb42f5-0603-4e2a-b1bc-835fbb6223a5] activesupport (5.0.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:750:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
[2adb42f5-0603-4e2a-b1bc-835fbb6223a5] activesupport (5.0.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.--More--
```

Comment: The error your provide is not enough to help you. Please post the full error message. Sometimes you can get the file that is causing it. Also have you changed something right before the error occurs ?

Comment: @Maxence i have shared the full log file above

Comment: @Tolga What is the ruby version you are using and rails version too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While searching for solution, I came across with a similar problem here: [Devise authentication error with ActionController::Responder and axlsx_rails gem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29461524/devise-authentication-error-with-actioncontrollerresponder-and-axlsx-rails-gem)

In the above problem, user mentioned axlsx-rails gem had a known problem with action controller (there was a action controller issue with axlsx-rails and he applied a patch for it.

Few days ago, I had also included axlsx-rails gem for XLSX exports from my app. In my case, I didn't have any problem after I included gem until today (I guess my login credentials were valid until today and when I needed to re-login today, I faced a problem)

I have searched for the gem file in the system then applied the patch manually:

```
gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/axlsx_rails-0.5.1/lib/axlsx_rails

ActionController::Renderers.add :xlsx do |filename, options|
  unless formats.include?(:xlsx) || Rails.version < '3.2'
    formats[0] = :xlsx
  end
```